# Populate list using a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have an array with properties that i want to transfer to a list using a `for loop`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.cars.Count; i++)
{
    var model = data.cars[i].model.ToString();
    cars = new List<Car>
    {
        new Car { Model = model }
    };
}
```

Keep getting a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:Index was out of range` exception. Not sure how to insert each model name in a new `Car` instance using a `for loop`.

EDIT:
`data.Count` was a typo, the same exception was thrown while using `data.cars.Count`. To clarify, the length of `data.cars.Count` is 20 objects containing a `model` property.

Comment: can you show us your `data.cars` ? why using `data.Count` and not `data.cars.Count` ?

Comment: Probably you should use _data.cars.Length_ if cars is an array or _data.cars.Count_ if cars is a list. However, you have other errors in your logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you could remove this loop and use a single linq line

```
var cars = data.cars.Select(x => new Car{ Model = x.model}).ToList();
```

Your actual code triggers the mentioned exception because whatever *data.Count* is, it is not equal to the number of elements in the *cars* collection. If *data.Count* is bigger than the numbers of element in the *data.cars* collection then the exception occurs.

However you have another logical error in your code, at each loop your code creates a new List containing a single Car element. At each loop your code assigns this list to the external variable *cars*. Of course, when the loop exits, you have your external variable *cars* assigned to a list with just the last element in the loop.

If you prefer a standard loop approach then you could write

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
foreach (var car in data.cars)
{
    cars.Add(new Car { Model = car.model });
}
```

Comment: Note: This answer relies on the original code `data.Count` which has been edited to `data.cars.Count` meanwhile.

Comment: I have not noticed the edit. This edit, however, makes the mentioned exception unexplainable for me.

Comment: I guess that the exception does not occur anymore. This edit probably invalidates the question as well as all the answers.

Comment: Did get the exception even if using data.cars.Count, data.Count was a typo. Using a foreach loop like the answer shows solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting that exception because number of data records may be higher than number of cars in each data. For example data may be a collection of 10 items but cars collection in each data record may only contain one or two elements. So, first, second and third iteration may work just fine but after that you'll get an exception.

Try following

```
foreach (var car in data.cars)
{
    var model = car.model.ToString();
    cars = new List<Car>
    {
        new Car { Model = model }
    };
}
```

Comment: explain why your version is different or better than his and you've got a good answer.

Comment: @bolov Yes, I was typing that.

Comment: Still you have not fixed another OP logical error here. How many list of cars are you creating here? And how many cars are in that list?

Comment: Want to create as many new Car as the lenght of data.cars.Count